# Which is the fastest emulator for making an android app?

Tags: android

I am recently using the android studio, and the emulator is working very slowly, which is really time consuming, everytime I run the ap on the emulator , it takes nearly 2 min to open and load, also , what are the best ways to know what is causing error in my app?

Comment: old version: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/995714 now simply use [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

Answer (score 2):

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is a good one. It's free for individual developers for basic features.

> **Development environment**
>
> Plugins for Android Studio and Eclipse. Compatible with all Android SDK tools.
>
> **High performance**
>
> Built from AOSP, optimized for speed and validated against the Compatibility Test Suite.

For me, default emulator works slower then Genymotion even with HAXM enabled.

Answering your second question,Best way to find an error is to look into logs and analyse them.

Android provides comprehensive logs in `logcat` which is embedded into development environments like eclipse and Android Studio.
`logcat` provides details of error with root cause and line number responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator runs slowly cause for primarily two reasons. First one is you do not have the appropriate software installed. Go to your SDK, the last few options should be to install " Intel (x86) Emulator or HAXM. Install this. Note that once you use SDK to download, you need to go to the location in explorer and install it manually.

Secondly, make sure your intel virtualization Technology is Active. There are many softwares that let you check it. Just google it. If it is de-active then you will have to change the settings from your BIOS.